# IPv4 regex in bash

Tags: regex, bash

Does anyone have any suggestions for my regex for IPv4. This does not completely validate an IPv4 address.

```
IPV4="^(|[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3})\|"
```

1.1.1.1 is ok, but 999.1.1.1 also validates :(

Thanks for the input

*** UPDATE ***

Based on DopeGhoti's input, here is where im at so far. I'm running into issues adding this into my larger regex. I am setting this regex equal to a variable and then combining it with another expression for IPv6 as well. There are a few things that I have added to the regex. For example a (|insert DopeGhoti regex here). This allows me to accept an empty IPv4 address too. I also added a \| at the end because the two addresses being checked by the one big regex are | delimited.

```
IPV4="^(|(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)))\|"
REGEX="$IPV4$IPV6"
```

This process works with my simplier IPv4 regex. Something in the new regex is breaking it.

*** UPDATE ***

Ok weird. I tested the following in rubular:

http://rubular.com/r/c6J3sESDyN

```
^(|(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)))\|$
```

This seems to work. Maybe I have another internal issue. Checking now.

Comment: 250.1.1.1 is a valid IP address.

Comment: Sorry, entered wrong example.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to escape the dot char ?

```
 # ^([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})

 ^ 
 (
      [0-9]{1,3} \. [0-9]{1,3} \. [0-9]{1,3} \. [0-9]{1,3} 
 )
```

Comment: That will also match 999.999.999.999

Comment: Thats true, but its the OP's regex, take it up with him, just showing the dot needs escaping so it doesn't match 999999999999

Answer (score 0):

You could try `(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))`.

Comment: This is very very close.

Comment: I edited this and tested it against several good and bad "addresses", this seems to very nearly work as intended.  It will still match `0.1.2.3` for example.

Comment: Unfortunately 255.255.255.257 still validates.

Comment: Not when I [test](http://i.imgur.com/yOTN4iZ.png)?

Comment: Try it in here http://rubular.com/

Comment: I did, [here](http://rubular.com/r/5xCdazWxeA).  If catching it as a substring is the problem, add `\b` at the start and end of the expression.  Also, thanks for Rubular, I'm adding that to my toolkit. (:

Comment: Actually, if someone placed a 192.168.268.13 somewhere, I'd say it _looks_ like an IP number.  So maybe the regexp should match even that (so actually, 999.999.999.999 should maybe, too) but a value-checker afterwards should reject it with a better error message than just "does not look like an IP number".

Comment: Well, now you're just moving the goalposts; you asked for complete IP4 address validation.  If you just want to match the numerical pattern without caring if it's actually an IP, you can use `([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}`.

Comment: That wasn't me lol. Lets not back track.

Comment: Please see my update above

Answer (score 0):

Post-Update:

If the merged regexes are failing while working individually, that you could try distilling each of the two expressions, and then test with:

```
egrep "(${IP4PATTERN}|${IP6PATTERN})" /path/to/file
```